# Basic app with webview not working - FC on start

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to create a simple webview and I am getting FC on each start.

Here is my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.jerdog.apps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.layout.main);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

and here is my res/layout/main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am including my logcat from the moment I press Run in Eclipse at pastebin

http://pastebin.com/5trRw9Bd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.layout.main);
```

is incorrect, and `myWebView` is null.  Thus the following line throws the `NullPointerException`

Change the line to:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

`findViewById` takes the id of the `View` you wish to find as an input, however you were passing in your layout.  Changing this to the id of the `WebView` element from your `main.xml` file should fix the issue.  There is a [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) if you need a reference implementation.

Comment: Well now I get it to load in the emulator, but nothing shows up except for the title bar.  I copied everything from the tutorial

Comment: Did you include step 4 where you add the `android.permission.INTERNET` to your `manifest`?

Comment: Yes - the mainActivity.java file - http://pastebin.com/z2fabdA3 and the main.xml file - http://pastebin.com/DdJ8ER4x  and the manifest file - http://pastebin.com/knNUcwQW

Comment: Does your emulator have working internet access?  Can you load google in the normal web browser?

Comment: yes - that was one of the first things I checked....  I was able to browse using the browser.

Comment: Had to rebuild my project and do it all again - but it worked.  Thanks Dave.c